# C Pointer Question: &(*struct->struct)

Tags: c, pointers

I have a struct defined with the structure as follows (names are different)

```
struct str1
{
   int field1;
   struct str2;
}
```

And I have a `*str1` in a function. I'd like to get a pointer to `str2`.

So I tried `&(str1->str2)` and was hoping this would return a pointer to `str2`. Is this incorrect? It doesn't seem to be working. How would I get a pointer to `str2` if given a pointer to `str1`?

Comment: Works fine for me; are you getting a compiler error? Can we see it?

Comment: &(str1->str2) is correct. Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Your "struct str1" declaration is bad.  It doesn't specify a variable in the "struct str2" declaration (e.g., "struct str2 str2;").

Comment: Can we see the actual code?  Is there a declaration for struct str2?  The second field in your str1 struct seems to be an empty declaration instead of a field definition.

Answer (score 4):

If `p` is a ponter to an object of `struct str1` type, then `&p->str2` will give your the pointer to its `str2` member (assuming it has `str2` member).

"Doesn't seem to be working" is not a meaningfull description of a problem. Your examples look suspicious though. The `struct str2` inside `struct str1` makes no sense. What is it supposed to be? A forward declaration of a struct type? And is your pointer really named `str1`? Same as the struct tag?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should be correct.  str1->str2 points you to the struct and taking its address whould get you a pointer to that value.

What is your debugger telling you?  Perhaps your str1 pointer is garbage?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer to str1, you may need to do:

&(*(str1).str2)

not really sure about this, but try it, I do not have a C compiler at hand.

Comment: &(*(str1).str2) is equivalent to &(str1->str2) :)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a pointer to another struct like below,

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct emp_1 {
  int id;
  char *name;
};

struct company {
  int id;
  char *name;
  struct emp_1 emp;
};

void main(void)
{
  struct company company;
  struct emp_1 *emp = (struct emp_1 *)&company;

  company.id = 100;
  company.name = "Payoda";
  emp -> id = 100;
  emp -> name = "Mohanraj";

  printf("emp id is : %d \n", emp -> id);
  printf("emp name is : %s \n", emp -> name);
}
```